Как передать экземпляр класса в роутер FastAPI?
Мне нужно передать в мои роутеры экземпляр Дискорд бота, чтобы в дальнейшем использовать этого бота в обработке запроса. Например: отправляется запрос на эндпоинт api/process_order/, в теле запроса передается айди ордера и бот должен отправить в определенный канал, что  ордер с таким айди был обработан.
У меня имеется файл api.py
import os
from nextcord.ext import commands
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends
from api_server.endpoints import orders, steam_authorization


def start_api(bot: commands.Bot):
    app = FastAPI()

    async def get_bot():
        return bot

    app.include_router(orders.router)
    app.include_router(steam_authorization.router)

    app.secret_key = os.urandom(24)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        import uvicorn

        uvicorn.run(app, port=5000)

Где я подключаю роутеры через функцию start_api. В этой функции должен передаваться аргумент bot.
В файле main.py и как раз вызываю функцию start_api, тем самым запускаю апи. В этой функции я передаю экземпляр бота.
import nextcord
from nextcord.ext import commands
from threading import Thread
from api import start_api

bot = commands.Bot(intents=nextcord.Intents.all())

Thread(target=start_api, args=(bot,)).start()
bot.run(TOKEN)

Теперь главный вопрос: Как мне передать в роутер, например orders.router, экземпляр этого бота, чтобы после использовать этого бота в самом роутере orders?

В самих роутах указывайте get_bot как зависимость (dependency), см. https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/

@insolor, то есть получается, что мне нужно изменить код добавления роутера на следующий: app.include_router(orders.router, dependencies=[Depends(get_bot)])? А как мне в самом роутере извлечь или получить этого бота?
Если я пытаюсь вывести print(router.dependencies), то выводит пустой список.

Нет, доабавляете в самих обработчиках, которые в роутере. Прямо в тех функциях, в которых нужен этот бот.

@insolor, не особо понял. Вот мой обработчик.
`@router.post("/api/process_order/{order_id}")
async def process_order(order_id: int, authorization: str = Header(None)):
if authorization is None or authorization != await get_token():
raise HTTPException(status_code=403, detail="Unauthorized")
print(bot)`

Как мне получить эту функцию get_bot, если она находится в другом файле?
У меня структура файлов такая:
main.py - сам запуск бота + вызов функции start_api
api.py - функция start_api
api_server/endpoints/orders.py - сам роутер

"как мне получить эту функцию get_bot" - импортировать. Вынести ее в модуль, где у вас бот создается, оттуда ее импортируете.

Получается циклический импорт
File "C:\bot\mcs_new\bot.py", line 9, in <module>     from api import start_api   File "C:\bot\mcs_new\api.py", line 4, in <module>     from api_server.endpoints import orders, steam_authorization   File "C:\bot\mcs_new\api_server\endpoints\orders.py", line 8, in <module>     from bot import get_bot   File "C:\bot\mcs_new\bot.py", line 9, in <module>     from api import start_api ImportError: cannot import name 'start_api' from partially initialized module 'api' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\bot\mcs_new\api.py)

Тогда наоборот сделайте, запуск сервиса в основном потоке, а бота в отдельном потоке.
